# @Async not asynchronous in Groovy

Tags: java, asynchronous, groovy, spring-boot

I am tasked with making our database writes asynchronous.  Sounds pretty simple on the surface, but the info I'm getting online isn't all that helpful and what I hear from co-workers is "asynch is tricky".  So, I'm hoping to get something more helpful than "play with it bit until you get it to work".  My code/call looks like this:`

```
@EnableAsync
@SpringCloudApplication
//To run as a FAT JAR:
//public class Application {
// Only extend when running as WAR
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }} 

public class MyClass{
    public void asyncCall(){
        if(1==1){
            DatabaseWriter.testAsync();
            System.out.println("past DatabaseWriter.testAsync() method");
            return;
        }
    }}

public class DatabaseWriter {
    @Async
    public static Future<Object> testAsync(){
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        println ("end of DatabaseWriter.testAsync() method");
        return null;
    }}
```

`
So, my output consistently comes out looking like this:

```
end of DatabaseWriter.testAsync() method 
past DatabaseWriter.testAsync() method
```

Obviously, the original method call is waiting for the return from the testAsync() method.  I'm looking for direction on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Async annotation works only for beans from the spring context, because spring creates proxy around async method. So if you create bean with new keyword:

```
new DatabaseWriter();
```

or if you put @Async annotation on static method it will not work, because there will be original method instead of proxy.

That example works well. To start the application just run the main method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}

@Component
class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppRunner2.class);
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseWriter writer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("---  start ---");
        writer.testAsync();
        logger.info("--- stop ---");
    }
}

@Component
class DatabaseWriter {
    @Async
    public Future<Object> testAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        AppRunner.logger.info("end of DatabaseWriter.testAsync() method");
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can try to replace line

```
writer.testAsync();
```

with

```
   new DatabaseWriter().testAsync();
```

and will see that the @Async doesn't work.

Comment: Between WyMuT-CoCHa and some further research, I found that the issue was not just the @Async annotation, but the class with that annotation had to be a bean so the calling class didn't create an instance with the "new" keyword.  Still don't understand it all, but this gets me closer and my code works.